# Windows batch split long string by length 64

Tags: string, batch-file, split

I have tried to figure this out without any luck. Can anyone help on this?

I have a file: input.txt
This file contains a long string - and i want to split the long string into 64 long string chunks, and save the content to a different file.

I don't have much so far, i know i have to use the for loop:

```
echo off
set /p base64=<input.txt

for /f "%base64:~0,64%" %%G IN %base64% DO echo %%G
```

But how to make the loop for each 64 characters in line - and in a batch script?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (input.txt) DO SET longline=%%i&call:breakit
)>output.txt
GOTO :eof

:breakit
ECHO %longline:~0,64%
SET longline=%longline:~64%
IF DEFINED longline GOTO breakit
GOTO :EOF
```

This should do what you want - but it may depend on the content of the file as batch has sensitivities to certain characters.

Comment: By the way .. i get an error when string in the file is to long with youre script...do you know why it could be?


Is there any limit to the length of the string in the text file?



I have a file that app. 11388 characters long. But it does not work with youre script.

But if i cut the string to 8183 characters the script works.

Strange...do you know why?

Comment: There are limits to many systems and utilities. CMD.EXE won't allow a string longer than 8183 characters. I believe FINDSTR is limited to ~4K. There are also limits to filename-lengths for instance. 8183 does seem a very strange number though - although it is correct (for a 3-character variable name like `var`) It's 8185 for 1 1-character name. That would be 8185+1 for the variable-name+1 for the '='+1 for the terminal `null` = 8188. So possibly there's a 4-byte pointer involved too, totalling a more 'binary' 8192.

Comment: ok thanks, so i have to use a different tool to split the file rather than a pure batch solution..