# Batch - how to set var using for /f from html

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, substring

In batch I'm using curl to output html to a file (output.txt) and a search of the output file is then sent to a new file (search.txt). The search result outputs a long line of about 4000 characters which include ( ) [ ] < > / " ; : , .

From this I'm trying to extract a var using for /f but it fails so instead I would like to split the long line into smaller lines in a new file using < /div > as the line break.

I've tried question [#16319355](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319355) which is similar but that approach also doesn't seem to work with special characters. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit: *as requested by Stephan*

This is a working example:

```
echo off
curl -L "https://cnn.com" >output.txt
findstr "bounty" "output.txt" | findstr "ad_oop_float_01" >search.txt
```

output.txt:

```
output.txt is too big for stackoverflow and pastebin
```

search.txt:

```
<div class="OUTBRAIN" data-src="" data-widget-id="TR_1" data-ob-template="cnnedition"></div><script>(function (d) {var e = d.createElement('script');e.async = true;e.type = 'text/javascript';e.onload = function _onJSMDLoad(e) {jQuery(d).triggerAnalyticsReady();};e.src = '//agility.cnn.com/turner/cnn-prod/Bootstrap.js';d.body.appendChild(e);})(document);</script><script src="/.a/2.212.2/js/cnn-footer-lib-react.min.js"></script><script async src="/.a/2.212.2/js/gigya-sharebar.min.js" type="text/plain" class="optanon-category-smv"></script><script src="//a.postrelease.com/serve/load.js?async=true"></script><script>if (WM.UserConsent.inUserConsentState(["perf-general"], {id: "usabilla"})) {CNN.INJECTOR.loadFeature('usabilla');}</script><script async src="//native.sharethrough.com/assets/sfp.js"></script><script>(function (doc, fd) {fd.measure(function () {var scpt = doc.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];fd.mutate(function () {WM.UserConsent.addScript({async: true,id: 'quantScript',src: (doc.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'https://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js' : 'http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js'),type: 'text/javascript'}, ["ads-vendor"], scpt.parentNode);});});}(document, fastdom));</script><noscript><img src="//pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-D1yc5zQgjmqr5.gif?labels=noscript%3ANo%20Labels%20Set" style="display: none;" border="0" height="1" width="1" alt="Quantcast"/></noscript><script>window._sf_async_config = window._sf_async_config || {};window._sf_async_config.uid = 37612;window._sf_async_config.domain = '' || 'edition.cnn.com';window._sf_async_config.flickerControl = false;window._sf_async_config.useCanonical = true;/* Prevent Chartbeat from automatically checking the page for videos */window._sf_async_config.autoDetect = false;var _sf_startpt=Date.now();WM.UserConsent.addScript({async: true,src: '//static.chartbeat.com/js/chartbeat_mab.js'}, ["perf-general"]);</script><script>(function(w, d, c, u) {var f, n, i;w[u] = w[u] || [],f = function () {var o = {ti: '5526986'};o.q = w[u];w[u] = new UET(o);w[u].push('pageLoad');},n = d.createElement('script'),n.async = 1,n.onload = n.onreadystatechange = function() {var s = this.readyState;s && s !== 'loaded' && s !== 'complete' || (f(), n.onload = n.onreadystatechange = null);},n.src = '//bat.bing.com/bat.js',i = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],c.UserConsent.addScriptElement(n, ["perf-vendor"], i.parentNode);})(window, document, WM, 'uetq');</script><script>if (!CNN.Features || CNN.Features.enableBounceX !== false) {(function (d) {WM.UserConsent.addScript({async: true,src: d.location.protocol + '//tag.bounceexchange.com/340/i.js'}, ["iab","behavior-vendor","person-vendor","storage-vendor"]);})(document);}</script><script>(function($){$(document).onZonesAndDomReady(function () {if (Modernizr.android === true) {$('head').append('<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">');$('head').append('<link href="//cdn.cnn.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/misc/cnn-logo.png" rel="icon" sizes="192x192">');}});}(jQuery));</script><script data-obct>!function(_window, _document) {var OB_ADV_ID = '00b2d6c56fc76084821b9d05abf2f201d9',api,tag,script;if (_window.obApi) {if (!Array.isArray(_window.obApi.marketerId)) {_window.obApi.marketerId = [_window.obApi.marketerId];}return;}api = _window.obApi = function () {var a = window.obApi;a.dispatch ? a.dispatch.apply(a, arguments) : a.queue.push(arguments);};api.version = '1.0';api.loaded = true;api.marketerId = OB_ADV_ID;api.queue = [];tag = _document.createElement('script');tag.async = true;tag.src = '//amplify.outbrain.com/cp/obtp.js';script = _document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];WM.UserConsent.addScriptElement(tag, ["iab","behavior-vendor"], script.parentNode);}(window, document);obApi('track', 'PAGE_VIEW');document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {var el = event.target;if (el && (el.tagName === 'A' || (el.parentNode && el.parentNode.tagName === 'A'))) {obApi('track', 'Exit Link Clicks');}});</script><script>if (WM.UserConsent.inUserConsentState(["perf-vendor","social-vendor"], {id: "twitterPixel"})) {(function (w, d) {var e,s;if (!w.twq) {s = w.twq = function () {s.exe ? s.exe.apply(s, arguments) : s.queue.push(arguments);};s.version = '1.1';s.queue = [];e = d.createElement('script');e.async = true;e.type = 'text/javascript';e.src = '//static.ads-twitter.com/uwt.js';d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(e);}})(window, document);twq('init', 'nyutn');twq('track', 'PageView');}</script><script>if (console) {console.log(' ');console.log('  .d8888b.  888b    888 888b    888');console.log(' d88P  Y88b 8888b   888 8888b   888');console.log(' 888    888 88888b  888 88888b  888    We are trying to make CNN.com faster.');console.log(' 888        888Y88b 888 888Y88b 888    Think you can help?');console.log(' 888        888 Y88b888 888 Y88b888');console.log(' 888    888 888  Y88888 888  Y88888    Send your ideas to: bounty AT cnnlabs DOT com');console.log(' Y88b  d88P 888   Y8888 888   Y8888');console.log('  "Y8888P"  888    Y888 888    Y888');console.log(' ');}</script><script>(function (win, doc, WM) {win['bt'] = win['bt'] || function () { (win['_bt'] = win['_bt'] || []).push(arguments); };WM.UserConsent.addScript({async: true,src: '//cdn.boomtrain.com/p13n/cnn/p13n.min.js'}, ["person-vendor"]);})(window, document, WM);</script><div class="ad ad--epic ad--all-skin"><div id="ad_oop_skin_01" class="ad-ad_oop_skin_01 ad-refresh-adbanner"></div></div><div class="ad ad--epic ad--all"><div id="ad_oop_float_01" class="ad-ad_oop_float_01 ad-refresh-adbody"></div></div><div class="ad ad--epic ad--all"><div id="ad_oop_float_02" class="ad-ad_oop_float_02 ad-refresh-adbody"></div></div></body></html>
```

From this example I would like to:

```
for /f "tokens=? delims=?" %%a in (search.txt) do (set "class=%%a")    
echo class="%class%"
class="ad-ad_oop_float_01 ad-refresh-adbody"
```

Comment: As it's already clear that you're aware of the batch file parser's limitations regarding some of those characters, why not use a scripting language which doesn't, and which was designed to select or replace substrings?

Comment: Compo I need to do this in batch and I'm not entirely aware of the limitations, I'm still working it all out. If someone could show me how to split a file I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Please describe in what manner your `for /F` attempt fails, because it cannot be due to line length limits since `for /F` can read lines of up to 8 KBytes (and you are talking about 4K characters)! what is the text encoding of `output.txt` (ASCII/ANSI, Unicode)?

Comment: aschipfl the encoding on `output.txt` is Unix (LF) UTF-8 but the file I'm interogating is `search.txt` Windows (CRLF) UTF-8. The problem is not line length, I'm getting odd results from `for /f` and I can't seem to find a suitable delimiter that does not exceed 26 but thank you I did not check for encoding. I've had that problem before and had to pipe text from file and back to file to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch is horrible to process such a string. Gladly [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053) wrote [jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044), a hybrid JScript/batch script with full REGEX support, which makes this task quite easy:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('^<test.txt jrepl.bat ".* class=\q(.*) .*" "$1" /XSEQ') do set "class=%%a"
echo class=%class%
```

You can get a full explanation of `jrepl` with `jrepl -?`

Comment: Thanks Stephan. This is a great alternative but in the end I was able to find a unique delimiter however I still need a solution for splitting a string into sub strings from a delimiter.

Comment: That's a completely different task with a completely different string. See my answer to your new question.